# How to convert a piece of R code into Shiny apps?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

A new self-learner for Shiny apps, still trying to explore the structure of Shiny apps. I have a piece of code which I want to convert into Shiny apps. I wonder if someone can walk me through how the process goes. My goal is to make the figure title/subtitle dynamic based on inputs (i.e., lnHR0, p_ctl0, tfu) to function. Thanks!!!

R code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

WR_sim_OC <- function(n_trt, n_ctl, lnHR0, p_trt0, med_ctl, tfu, enroll, dur_boost){
  #n_trt=60: number of subjects (treatment)
  #n_ctl=30: number of subjects (control)
  #lnHR0=log(1): Overall Survival Log Hazard Ratio
  #p_trt0 = seq(0.46, 0.66, 0.01): Response Rate (Treatment)
  #med_ctl=21.8: Median Overall Survival (Control)
  #tfu=9: Minimum Follow-up Time
  #enroll=19: Enrollment Time
  #dur_boost=0: Durability Boost (percentage)
  
  ## insert real simulation code here ##
  
  ## Fake Results
  results <- tibble(ORR_trt = p_trt0, avg_HR = rep(0.774, times = 4), maturity = rep(36.7, times = 4), ORR = c(20.71, 38.87, 60.61, 78.95), 
                        WR = c(46.8, 56.0, 64.3, 72.8), WO = c(46.0, 55.0, 63.7, 71.9), OS = rep(55.0, times = 4))

  ## Create Operating Characteristic Figure
  dat <- results %>% pivot_longer(c(ORR, WR, WO, OS), names_to = 'Method', values_to = 'POS') 
  
  out1 <- ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = ORR_trt, y = POS, group = Method)) +
    geom_line(aes(color = Method), size = 1) +
    geom_point(aes(color = Method), size = 2.5) + 
    theme(legend.position = 'bottom') + 
    labs(title = 'HR=1.0 Treatment vs. Control', subtitle = 'ORR in Control Arm=46%, 9mo follow-up', color = 'Method') + 
    ylab('Probability of Incorrect Go') + 
    xlab('ORR in Treatment Arm') +
    ylim(0, 100)
  
  ## Output OC Table + Figure to shiny app
  list(results, out1)
}

WR_sim_OC(n_trt=60, n_ctl=30, lnHR0=log(1), p_ctl0=0.46, p_trt0 = seq(0.46, 0.66, 0.06), med_ctl=21.8, tfu=9, enroll=19, dur_boost=0)
```

I tried writing the ui.R as follows (suppose the suv_plot is the output name), which I know is wrong. The server.R part is too hard for me... Can someone help?

```
fluidPage(
  numericInput("lnHRO", 
               label = h3("ln(HRO)"), 
               value = log(1)),
  numericInput("pctl", 
               label = h3("Response Rate (Control)"), 
               value = 0.46),
  numericInput("tfu", 
               label = h3("Minimum Follow-up Time (Month)"), 
               value = 9),
  hr(),
  plotOutput("suv_plot")
  
)
```

Comment: I don't know of any StackExchange sites that are intended to be used as complete *tutorials* or *lesson plans*, and SO is no exception. While many answers do have sufficient detail to be useful as a mini-howto or such, I believe that that is the exception. And asking for that much is off-topic, please see [help/on-topic]. (And your question reads as *"do my work for me"*, which is generally unpopular and not likely to get much help.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Actually I finished a starting course on LinkedIn for the basic Shiny, but it is still really hard when I tried to put a function into a Shiny app. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion is just to look at tutorials on shiny, they give a great overview on how to start a project: https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/

I didn't know a thing about programming a few years back, so I understand it can be hard figuring out where to start, so I wanted to give you an idea of how to implement a function, and use shiny inputs to make the resulting table/plot be dynamic.

I switched up your code to be easier to reproduce for myself. I hope this gives you the starting point you need:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

WR_sim_OC <- function(MPG, CYL, DISP){
  
  results <- mtcars%>% #Function to make a table
    filter(cyl > CYL,
           mpg > MPG,
           disp > DISP)
  
  out1 <- ggplot(data = results, aes(x = mpg, y = disp, group = cyl)) +
    geom_line(aes(color = hp), size = 1) #Function to make a plot
  
  list(results, out1) #List to create table and function
}



ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("MilesPerGallon", "mpg", value = 15),
  numericInput("Cylinders", "cyl", value = 4),
  numericInput("Displacement", "disp", value = 200),
  tableOutput("TABLE"),
  plotOutput("PLOT")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$TABLE<-renderTable({
    req(input$MilesPerGallon, input$Cylinders, input$Displacement) #Requires all three inputs before it makes the table
    
    WR_sim_OC(input$MilesPerGallon, input$Cylinders, input$Displacement)[1] #Only pulling the table from the function
    
  })
  
  output$PLOT<-renderPlot({
    req(input$MilesPerGallon, input$Cylinders, input$Displacement) #Requires all three inputs before it makes the plot
    
    WR_sim_OC(input$MilesPerGallon, input$Cylinders, input$Displacement)[2] #Only pulling the plot from the function
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Essentially on the server side where you render the plot or table, you use those inputs from the ui as the dynamic points in your function. I used req() for both of the renderTable and renderPlot to make sure the inputs are filled out before it makes the table plot. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful! My following question is if I want to use separate ui.R and server.R, where should I put the R function "WR_sim_OC", in ui.R or server.R? Thanks!

Comment: I put it in the server.R, and it works fine! Thank so much! I really appreciate your warm encourage!